# <p> tag not being rendered properly in erb file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, dom, render, erb

I have a list like so

```
[
    {"name": "ryan", 
    "age": "12", 
    "gender":"male"
    },
    
]
```

And I have code to render each value in the hash in the list like so:

```
         <div>
            <% @list.each do |student| %>
                <%= student.each do |k,v|%>
                    <p> <%=v%> </p>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
```

I would expect each value (ryan, 12 , male) to be wrapped in the `<p>` tag however, for some reason the first value Ryan does not get wrapped in the tag when looking at the DOM. [image]

It can be seen that the `<p>` tag is empty where Ryan should be. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= student.each do |k,v|%>
```

is printing tag, you can use try using a non-printing tag(tag without =)

```
<% student.each do |k,v|%>
```

More about ERB tags [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_template_erb.html)